# Performance issues after activating second remote Data Guard

Tags: oracle, dataguard, standby, archive-log

I have a primary database that has two remote data guard. Second data guard was configured for a DC migration on new DC.

Second remote data guard was installed on the same DC (and subnet) with primary database. So, archive log gaps were transfered in local network after the full restore.

Performance issues have been started after physically moving the new data guard to its own DC.

We have noticed that the interface of the firewall struggled with its 1 gbps capacity. Therefore, we have limited the bandwidth with 150 mbps. Everything was good after this limitation .

However, general system performance was terrible during the week. I saw lots of locked sessions and active sessions that were waiting like 15-30 seconds. It is not normal of course.

When I checked v$archived_log table,
creator column is half with ARCH and LGWR for dest_id : 3 (new remote) during all slow performance hours. However, creator columb is full of LGWR for dest_id : 2 (old remote data guard.

Here are the dest_2 and dest_3 parameter values:

Log_archive_Dest_2: service= xyz NOAFFIRM ASYNC valid_for…
Log_archive_Dest_3: service= abc LGWR ASYNC valid_for…

I changed dest_3 with NOAFFIRM ASYNC. There is no ARCH creator for dest_is :3.  But system is not in load and will not be during the week.

Even though dest_3 configured with LGWR, i see lots of ARCH creator values. Of course, this might not be the reason, but the symptom.

So maybe, lgwr can not handle two remote data guard concurrently (i know that another process takes this responsibility, not the lgwr itself), and during those hours ARCH takes the lead. However, if it was the reason i should have seen some ARCH creator for dest_id : 2 as well.

Therefore, something should wrong with LGWR ASYNC definition.

According to the Oracle docs, if DB is in max performance mode and if ASYNC is selected, NOAFFIRM is also chose by default. So LGWR ASYNC does not mean LGWR ASYNC (AFFIRM).

Any thoughts, ideas?

Thanks.